# Oracle SQL Out put two table at a query

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
ID int,
name VARCHAR(70), 
price NUMBER(8,2),
primary key (ID, name)
);


drop table Instock;
/* Delete the tables if they already exist */

create table Instock (
    ID int,
    quantity int
);
```

I have two table in my database. i want to have two table showing a output as a table that look like this

```
ID Name Price Quantity
```

Comment: What have your tried? Search Google for `table joins` in Oracle / SQL Server / MySQL and read a few articles for a while. Somebody please close this. It's not a real question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.ID,A.NAME,A.PRICE,B.QUANTITY FROM Products A,Instock B WHERE A.ID=B.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to create the new table(this creates the table in addition to putting the data in there)

`CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE as SELECT A.ID,A.NAME,A.PRICE,B.QUANTITY FROM Products A,Instock B WHERE A.ID=B.ID`

Comment: @HarryWu did you have a chance to try the solution ?